# Creating curved lines Python Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

In this tutorial (https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-maps/ 23), the lines connecting the points are curved. However I can’t seem to recreate this behavior when using mapbox, i.e. go.Scattermapbox. With Scattermapbox the lines created are straight as shown on this page https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-mapbox/ 10. Are there any options or workarounds to join points using curved lines when using mapbox?

Thanks in advance!

```
flight_paths = []
for i in range(len(flights)):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scattergeo(
            lon = [flights['START_LON'][i], flights['DEST_LON'][i]],
            lat = [flights['START_LAT'][i], flights['DEST_LAT'][i]],
            mode = 'lines',
            line = dict(width = 1,color = 'red'),
            
        )
    )
```

Comment: I think the reason why the examples referenced in the tutorial are curved is because the projection_type is set. If the setting is disabled, the lines will be straight. My guess from this is that some logic is at work depending on the projection specified. Also, there doesn't seem to be an item in the map box to specify the projection. See here for [details](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/#base-maps-in-layoutmapboxstyle).

Answer (score 0):

On mapbox  the endpoints must be interpolated via `slerp` function (spherical "linear" interpolation):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, sin, cos
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def point_sphere(lon, lat):
    #associate the cartesian coords (x, y, z) to a point on the  globe of given lon and lat
    #lon longitude
    #lat latitude
    lon = lon*pi/180
    lat = lat*pi/180
    x = cos(lon) * cos(lat) 
    y = sin(lon) * cos(lat) 
    z = sin(lat) 
    return np.array([x, y, z])

def slerp(A=[100, 45], B=[-50, -25], dir=-1, n=100):
    #Spherical "linear" interpolation
    """
    A=[lonA, latA] lon, lat given in degrees; lon in  (-180, 180], lat in (-90, 90]
    B=[lonB, latB]
    returns n points on the great circle of the globe that passes through the  points A, B
    #represented by lon and lat
    #if dir=1 it returns the shortest path; for dir=-1 the complement of the shortest path
    """
    As = point_sphere(A[0], A[1])
    Bs = point_sphere(B[0], B[1])
    alpha = np.arccos(np.dot(As,Bs)) if dir==1 else  2*pi-np.arccos(np.dot(As,Bs))
    if abs(alpha) < 1e-6 or abs(alpha-2*pi)<1e-6:
        return A
    else:
        t = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
        P = sin((1 - t)*alpha) 
        Q = sin(t*alpha)
        #pts records the cartesian coordinates of the points on the chosen path
        pts =  np.array([a*As + b*Bs for (a, b) in zip(P,Q)])/sin(alpha)
        #convert cartesian coords to lons and lats to be passed to go.Scattermapbox
        lons = 180*np.arctan2(pts[:, 1], pts[:, 0])/pi
        lats = 180*np.arctan(pts[:, 2]/np.sqrt(pts[:, 0]**2+pts[:,1]**2))/pi
        return lons, lats

lons, lats = slerp(A=[-111.5, 25], B=[-56, 49], dir=1)

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(lon=lons, lat=lats, mode="lines", line_color="red"))
fig.update_layout(width=800, mapbox= dict(accesstoken=open(".mapbox_token").read().rstrip(),
                  center_lat= 37.72199960022625, center_lon= -94.65000604447964,
                  zoom=2.5,
                  style="basic" ))
```

[image]